# PHP: return values from foreach inside a custom function

Tags: php, foreach

I wrote a foreach loop and saved on several lines of code. It basically takes all of the $_POST variables and uses their names to create normal php variables.

```
foreach(array_keys($_POST) as $str)
{
${$str}=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,trim($_POST["$str"]));
}
```

It is working as expected, creating variables dynamically.

Now, I wanted to put it inside a custom function so i modified it like this:

```
function createvariablesfromPOST()
{
    foreach(array_keys($_POST) as $str)
    {
    ${$str}=mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS["connection"],trim($_POST["$str"]));
    }
    return //something;
}
```

Its not working obviously, because i dont know how to make this function return // something (whatever that thing may be) to the global scope. Whats supposed to be done here?

I cant make the foreach loop return anything, till the loop is complete. Isn't that so?

Please help.

Comment: What you're doing is the great example of what you should **never** do

Comment: You could only return once and only one item (where "item" is one variable which also could be an array holding multiple values then). To use your automagically created variables outside the function, you would have to set them as global. But as mentioned above, you should think about an more reliable solution.

Comment: Hi, @Phil: I'm reading the page you mentioned

Comment: @zerkms: I have a naming convention, where the names of columns from the MySQL db and the name attributes in the html form are the same. It didnt make sense to duplicate it so many times. The users may either enter values or leave it blank. Why do you think its a problem?

Comment: @Chinmay Kamat: it is a problem because you want your variables to be global. I cannot even think of how using some database values as html attributes can justify using global variables.

Comment: There's a reason why `register_globals` has been disabled and is now deprecated! http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning arbitrary variables supplied by the user could be EXTREMELY DANGEROUS! They can overwrite any of your variables.

The reason it isn't working, is because they aren't in the global [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).  You would have to do something like `$GLOBALS[$variable] = 'something';`

Instead, you should assign the variables to an array so they are isolated from the global scope.  i.e. `$input[$$var] = $escaped_value`;

Comment: Thanks, Your suggestion of making the variable global inside the foreach loop itself has worked. But I'm examining the possibility of conflict as you and others have pointed out.